# How to remove specific tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
html = '<font><a>Test Message</a></font>';

html = html.find('font').remove();
```

Expecting Output:

```
<a>Test Message</a>
```

Actually this code is not working. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you add complete code, live snippet/jsfiddle demo

Comment: how does the tag (which has to be removed) look like ?

Comment: what values has the html value have?

Comment: You can only remove if html is appended in dom.First append that in Dom and then Remove that.

Comment: You should apply [`unwrap`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) on the `a` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've a **string** that contains HTML markup, you can use string replace functions to remove unwanted elements.

To remove only `<font>` and `</font>` you can use regex here.

```js
html = '<font><a>Test Message</a></font>';
html = html.replace(/<\/?font>/g, '');

document.getElementById('result').innerText = html;
console.log(html);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**Regex Explanation:**

`/<\/?font>/g` matches `<font>` and `</font>` strings. `\/?` will match zero or one `/`.

**Warning:** The `g` flag in the regex will replace all the matches in the string. So, if the string contains more than one `font` elements, all will be removed.

**Note:** Using jQuery's `remove()` will also remove the descendants of the `<font>`.

---

You can also use jQuery's `html()` methods as follow:

```js
html = '<font><a>Test Message</a> </font>';
html = $(html).html();

// To show result on page
$(document.body).text(html);
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove elements and content, there are mainly two jQuery methods you should use:

- `$(html).find(selector).remove()` - Removes the selected element (and its child elements)
- `$(html).find(selector).empty()` - Removes the child elements from the selected element

Give more detailed code if you need more detailed answer with right selector.

Links to jQuery for [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) methods.

Comment: Both the answers, `remove` and `empty` are not helpful in this case. They both will remove the anchor element inside the `font`, here OP wants to remove only `<font>` and `</font>` and not their children/descendants.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery unwrap to remove the parent of the `a` tag  `font`
Then append it to a dynamicaly created div and call the `html` method to get the result
try:

```
  html =  $('<div>').append($(html).find('a').unwrap()).html();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p0acop2k/

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this

```
$(html).find('font').remove();
```

> as @Tushar commented Note: This'll also remove the anchor element
>   inside `<font>`, resulting in giving empty string,

so you can use

```
html = '<font><a>Test Message</a></font>';
new_html = $(html).find('a').clone(); // this is just an anchor
// now your new html is <a>Test Message</a>
```

Comment: Note: This'll also remove the anchor element inside `<font>`, resulting in giving empty string, might not what OP wants

Comment: Regarding your second snippet: You don't need last statement, you can use `new_html` to get anchor tag markup. And this will work for the given example, what if the string contains `<div>` and not `<a>` or both `<div>` and `<a>`.

Comment: @Tushar you know more than me in jquery and javascript .. so I believe you know if we will open our mind for assuming we will find more and more of different solutions .. here we have a case in question and trying to work with this case .. That's it

Answer (score 1):

```
html = $('<font><a>Test Message</a></font>');
html.find('font').contents().unwrap();
console.log(html.html());
```